# Sample Space & Random Experiment (Hat Check)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

The hatcheck experiment with n = 4 hats. (In this experiment, n people check their hats. When someone comes to claim his/her hat, they are given one of the unclaimed hats, not necessarily their own. Thus, the hats are redistributed, one to each person.) How many of the outcomes in S result in nobody getting their own hat.

From my understanding:

S = {1,2,3,4} hats

|S| = 4! = 24

I calculated by writing out all of the possibilities which resulted in 11 (Not even sure if it is correct) However, I was wondering what the proper way of calculating this random occurence would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are in fact $9$ out of the $24$ possibilities that give nobody getting their own hat. If the hats start ABCD, then the solutions are

BADC
BCDA
BDAC 
CADB
CDAB
CDBA
DABC
DCAB
DCBA

Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) gives general calculation methods: with $n$ people and hats, the solution is $\left[\dfrac{n!}{e}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of four items.  For $n$ items there are $\frac {n!}e$, rounded.  For $4$ items, there are $9$.  The values are in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000166)